# Remove line breaks from database field values

Tags: php, string-formatting, sanitization

I'm building a routine that creates a ***settings.ini*** file from a database table.

I have a potential problem with the output file when the option value stored in the DB contains line breaks.

For example, like the "test_custom_css" setting below...

```
test_current_sort = asc
test_custom_css = /*.blog ul li {margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;}

#facebook_like iframe {height:30px;}

.footer ul li:last-child a {border:none;}
*/
test_custom_footer = true
test_custom_header = true
test_friendlyURLS = 1
```

Is there a PHP filter I can apply to the $mySettings variable in the loop below to remove the line breaks?

```
function wpseTest()
{
    $query = "SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options where option_name like 'test|_%' escape '|' AND option_value > ''";
    global $wpdb;
    $matches = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    $mySettings = '[settings]\r\n';

    foreach ($matches as $result){
        $mySettings .= $result->option_name;
        $mySettings .= ' = ';
        $mySettings .= $result->option_value; //REMOVE LINE BREAKS HERE
        $mySettings .= '\r\n';
    }

    $mySettingsFileLocation = WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/test/settings-backup.ini';
    $mySettingsFile = fopen($mySettingsFileLocation, 'w');
    fwrite($mySettingsFile, $mySettings);
    fclose($mySettingsFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$x = preg_replace('/\r\n|\r|\n\r|\n/m', ' ', $x);
```

removes all line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mySettings = str_replace("\r\n", "", $mySettings);
?>
```